# /Products/Debug-iphoneos/: No such file or directory Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIE4T.png)

After investigating, It turn out that i do not have Debug-iphoneos directory, but Debug-iphonesimulator directory instead. But i still don't know how to fix it. Please help.

SOLVED:
I have found a solution for it. To anyone who got the same problem as me. Let's go to the .sh file that appear one line before the error (look at the photo). open it, then change Debug-iphoneos to Debug-iphonesimulator. Then change this file permission to read only, and lock it, so xcode cannot modify or replace.

Comment: You cannot access xcode 8?

Comment: no, i can access xcode, but when i run the app, i get this error.

Comment: Please comment as to whether your problem has been answered by the duplicate so I know if you ned further help

Comment: no, it is not. But i have found a solution for it. To anyone who got the same problem as me. Let's go to the .sh file that appear one line before the error (look at the photo). open it, then change Debug-iphoneos to Debug-iphonesimulator. Then change this file permission to read only, and lock it, so xcode cannot modify or replace.